# Python Unit Test - compare content of iterables in Python < 2.7

Tags: python

How can I check if an array of custom class is sorted in the order that I want? 
I know that there is assertSequenceEqual in Python 2.7 and up, but I'm using Python 2.6, and while I might be able to do this using a forloop... is there better something in Python < 2.7 that I can use?

```
  actual_sorted = list.sort()

  expected_sorted = [MyClass("wed", 20), 
                     MyClass("wed", 19,),
                     MyClass("thu", 18,),
                     MyClass("wed", 17,)]

  self.assertEqual(actual_sorted, expected_sorted) # Well, this doesn't work.
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If your `MyClass` has an appropriate `__eq__` method, `assertEqual` should work on this.  What is it that doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As BrenBarn said, you have to add an `__eq__` method. I was writing a full example in parallel before I saw his answer:

```
import unittest


class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, day_name, day_num):
        self.day_name = day_name
        self.day_num = day_num

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return other.day_name == self.day_name and other.day_num == self.day_num


class ATestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_foo(self):
        actual_sorted = [MyClass("wed", 20),
                           MyClass("wed", 19),
                           MyClass("thu", 18),
                           MyClass("wed", 17)]

        expected_sorted = [MyClass("wed", 20),
                           MyClass("wed", 19),
                           MyClass("thu", 18),
                           MyClass("wed", 17)]
        self.assertEqual(actual_sorted, expected_sorted)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: -1 You don't have to add an `__eq__` - there are other ways possible.

Comment: @Marcin: Yes, you do- at least, it is the best approach.

Comment: @DavidRobinson Is it though? What if you only want to test equality in this way for the purposes of unit testing?

Comment: This is almost certainly a good method for equality anyway (though only someone maintaining the software would know for sure). The class as it is has only two attributes. The chance that someone would use equality to mean "exact same object" and not "shares both attributes" is extremely low.

Comment: @DavidRobinson Not really. If that behaviour were desired, a tuple would suffice. One of the main reasons for having a specific class would be to have a more sophisticated `__eq__` or other comparison methods.

Answer (score 0):

```
from operator import eq as equals
self.assertTrue(all(map(equals,actual_sorted, expected_sorted)))
```

This tests equality element-by-element. Of course, you may need to define your own `equals` if you do not wish to define an `__eq__` on the class in question (and you may well not want to, because defining an `__eq__` will likely change the behaviour of the programme, as well as the unit tests).

Comment: `assertEquals` will already do this. You just need to have an `__eq__` method defined for the class.

Comment: In fact, if there's no `__eq__` defined, won't this fail anyhow?  [Unless the two sequences contain the same instances, I guess, which a sort routine should probably return.  I was thinking of the OP's example, though, where there are two separate `MyClass("wed", 20)` instances.]

Comment: @DSM Primitive types all have an eq defined.

Comment: @JiMun There is a default `__eq__` defined in `object`. Please quantify "didn't work".

Comment: @DSM Unless MyClass is oldstyle, it will have an eq.

Comment: @Marcin: yeah, it has an `__eq__`, but not a useful one.  MyClass("wed", 20) != MyClass("wed", 20), so unless the OP defined one, the code given wouldn't work.

Comment: -1: Adding `__eq__` will solve the problem on its own, while using the `all` approach above doesn't help anything.

Comment: @DavidRobinson It's only a solution if the main programme (as opposed to the unit tests) operates in exactly the same way whatever definition is supplied for `__eq__`.

Comment: At least the answer here should show the `equals` function as it would need to be defined (I'd happily cancel my downvote if it did): I feel that otherwise it just doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @DavidRobinson given that no details of `MyClass` are given, that is simply not possible, and would in any case focus this answer on the specifics of OP's implementation.